# Real time programming in robotics with c++

Tags: c++, real-time, robotics

I am working on a robotics project with C++ and [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV). In this step, I have faced a problem which consists of:

I have two methods `moveRight()` and `moveLeft()` that I called successively in my code, but the problem is that the second one does not run, because the first one needs time (the time of robot movement), but when I put `Sleep(5000)` between them (I guessed that five seconds are enough for the movement), all is OK.

What is a programming solution that avoid the use of `Sleep` (because it makes some other problems)?

Comment: Did you try multithreading?

Comment: I created a robot control program for handling computer wafers. It could seamlessly change course in the middle of a move, based perhaps on data collected when the wafer passed through a laser light skirt. It is not a simple problem. I used a realtime operating system, with custom hardware that provided feedback to sync the controller with the robot. There is not nearly enough info in the question to begin to answer it. If this is a commercial project, I might be able to consult.

Comment: Maybe this Question fits better into http://robotics.stackexchange.com/ than StackOverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to add a [layer of indirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection). Add a queue of actions to perform, enqueue actions to moveLeft and moveRight, and somewhere else (different thread) execute actions from the queue correctly by waiting for previous action to complete before you do next action. Ideally you need a way to check if action is finished, so you can code it in a event based fashion.

Comment: You are right, in fact i can get the event of finished/not finished action. So i have to create a queue of all my action and execute them one by one from it taking into consideration the waiting time of each previous action.
I suppose that such a queue may be a list or functions pointers, isn't it?
Thanks very much Karthik

Comment: @HoussemBdr glad to hear I have been of help. yes, list of function pointers might be the simplest situation, but im guessing eventually you will get to the point where you want to pass arguements as well, then a family of functors would be better, or a basic command structure with all the logic implemented at the dequeueing side. btw could you mark the answer as accepted if it has resolved your query?

Comment: thanks, i have no problem with functions parameters, so the first solution is the best

Comment: I filled in the actions queue. but each of these actions need the context of robot(its actual positions at that precise time). So, how can i correct that?

Comment: @HoussemBdr You would need to hold a pointer(or better yet, reference) to the robot I suppose? Each action, or the queue as a whole

Comment: I didn't understand your idea. I explain more, to do such task, my work is devided in some steps:

step1: fill in queue actions, each action has a parameter called current_status which is the context of the robot that contains the actual positions, so the current_status is replaced by its value when filling in the queue (here is the problem).

Step 2: An updater is been launching so that after checking the status of robot (moving or not) so that here we need the current_status to realize the action but it's already filled in by older values.

I used volatile variable but in vain. idea? thx

Comment: instead of `current_status`, use `robot*` variable ?

Answer (score 2):

You should never "guess" in robotics. You should **KNOW**, **MEASURE** how long your movement takes and use that in your code. For instance call `moveRight()` often and have it check how long it has been running. Make it return `true` when it's running and use that as a condition to call `moveLeft()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer and when performing MoveRight() set the timer on 5 seconds, and after timer ends, perform Moveleft().